# Some images not showing up in IE, but in Chrome. When I replace it with another it works

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I'm designing a new portfolio website by using a template. Now I'm replacing the gallery with images with my own images, but something is going wrong. My own images are not visible in IE, but **it works in Chrome**. I know the codes can't be a problem because when I change it back to the original image, it works fine in both Chrome and IE.

When I "right click>properties" I can't see any details when I'm using my own image for example the URL. When I'm using the original image I actually can see this details.

I tried a number of things:

1. Change .jpg to .png --> doens't work
2. Change size from own image to size original image --> doens't work
3. Change filename --> doesn't work
4. Delete this image from the image folder and replace it --> doensn't work

Anyone who knows what can be the problem here? My site isn't published yet, so I'm still working with previews in dreamweaver.

Comment: Are your images RGB or CMYK? Anything less than IE9 won't support CMYK. If it's not that, please upload your website so we can see the source code.

Comment: My images are RGB and I'm testing in IE11.

Comment: Okay, at this stage we'll need to see a live working version of the site. It's difficult to analyse the problem otherwise.